# [Magento2.2.6]What is the purpose of tables which have tmp/replica/idx as a postfix?

Tags: database, magento2.2, table

I'm trying to insert queries in order to add products to our Magento website. 
I have no idea about these tables i mentioned at title like `catalog_category_product_index_replica`, `catalog_category_product_index_store1`,`catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica`.

When i implement quires, should i insert values into those tables?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

These tables are used for indexing you don't need to add any data into these tables. When indexer is ran these tables will be autofilled.

However for details you can read in .[Magento Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html#indexer-table-switching)